# Spring Data - Spring Boot findFirst retrieve twice the same document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using SpringBoot and SpringData with MongoDB.

It's a REST service with the `@RestController` annotation. It calls another component that is the `ChuckNorrisCommand`:

```
@Component
public class ChuckNorrisCommand extends AbstractCommand {

    /**
     * command name.
     */
    private static final String CHUCK_COMMAND_NAME = "chuck";

    /**
     * repository to retrieve data form DB.
     */
    @Autowired
    private ChuckNorrisRepository chuckNorrisRepository;
    /**
     * repository to access gif from db.
     */
    @Autowired
    private ChuckNorrisGifRepository gifRepository;

    /**
     * main method for the command.
     * @param request the request object that triggered the command
     * @return a quote
     */
    @Override
    public final ResponseToSlack executeCommand(final SlackRequest request) {
        final ChuckNorrisQuote chuckQuote = this.chuckNorrisRepository.findFirstByLastDisplayedDateIsNullOrderByRankAsc();
        chuckQuote.setLastDisplayedDate(new Date());
        this.chuckNorrisRepository.save(chuckQuote);
        final List<ChuckNorrisGif> all = this.gifRepository.findAll();
        final int randomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * (((all.size() - 1)) + 1));
        final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        out.append(chuckQuote.getQuote()).append(" <").append(all.get(randomIndex).getUrl()).append('>');

        return new ResponseToSlack(ResponseTypeEnum.IN_CHANNEL, out.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Command name.
     * @return command name.
     */
    @Override
    public final String getName() {
        return CHUCK_COMMAND_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Command description.
     * @return command description.
     */
    @Override
    public final String getDescription() {
        return "Get a very nice Chuck Norris quote and a gif to go with it.";
    }
}
```

And here is the `ChuckNorrisRepository` :

```
public interface ChuckNorrisRepository extends MongoRepository<ChuckNorrisQuote, ObjectId> {
    ChuckNorrisQuote findFirstByLastDisplayedDateIsNullOrderByRankAsc();
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is with the `ChuckNorrisRepository`. When I'm testing locally, each call to the service has the expected behaviour: I get a new document from the MongoDB collection.

But when deploy on my "production" environment, it takes 2 calls to the service to get a different document. And this is reproducible, it really takes 2 calls to get a new document.

I activated the MongoDB connector logs and I do see that the request is executed on each service call. Since the document is updated I was also able to check that the collection is correctly updated, so for me the problem is between data retrieval and data presentation.

The main difference that I noted between the 2 environments (and quite frankly, I don't know why it behaves like that) When I start the SpringBoot executable jar on my computer, I end up with a tomcat that has only one thread, but on production I have 34 threads running for the SpringBoot application.

I'm really at a point where I don't know what to look for on the internet and what to test to get more insights on what is going on.

Thanks for your time and your wisdom!

**EDIT : Workaround**

I changed the mechanism to use a counter instead of a date and it works correctly now.
I probably should report this to spring as I really don't know what's happening.

Comment: On lighter note `ChuckNorrisRepository` will do whatever at its own will :)

Comment: ho do you call the server side? Do you use JQuery? sometimes JQuery sends multiple calls.. if you are using JQuery try to use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. More information here: https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/. I hope it is useful

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond : I was expecting something like that at some point :)

Comment: @AngeloImmediata : Nope, plain old `cURL` command executed from a shell on both case (locally and on production)